# How did Kosh know to tell Sheridan to jump into the abyss on Z'ha'dum?

Tags: babylon-5

In the climactic scene for finale of season 3 of Babylon-5, Captain John Sheridan goes to Z'ha'dum with his presumed deceased wife, Anna Sheridan. She brings him to an underground complex in their capitol city.

> He sends a remote signal to his spaceship telling it to activate two 500 megaton nuclear weapons aboard it and plunge directly into the Shadow's capital city. As he waits for the spaceship to descend and destroy the city, Anna and two Shadows corner him on a balcony overlooking an abyss in the Shadow city. Kosh tells him **"Jump! Jump now!"**

How did Kosh know to tell him to jump?

Does the novelization or any canon source say the Vorlons knew what/whom was at the bottom of [abyss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abyss_(religion))?

Comment: This event is the only known instance of a pebble voting during an avalanche.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because Kosh knows that Lorien is there. The Shadows certainly do.

From Season 4 Episode 2 "Whatever Happened to Mr. Garibaldi":

> Lorien: You're the first to make it this far.
>
> Sheridan: Do they [the Shadows] know?
>
> Lorien: Of course. That's why they come back to Z'Ha'Dum every time they're driven off. Because I'm here. They think they're showing respect. They don't understand. They used to. But that was a long time ago. A million years.
>
> Sheridan: You don't look a—
>
> Lorien: No, I don't. Well, not at the moment.
>
> Glowy thing: Who are you?
>
> Sheridan: That was you.
>
> Lorien: Perhaps. We all have secrets and surprises. Did you know you have a Vorlon inside you? Well, a piece of one.
>
> Kosh (in flashback): If you go to Z'Ha'Dum, you will die.
>
> Kosh (in flashback): Jump. Jump now!
>
> Sheridan: Kosh.
>
> Lorien: Is that its name? I think I met it once long ago.
>
> Sheridan: He told me to jump. Did he know?
>
> Lorien: That I was here? Almost certainly.

(Transcript taken from [Springfield! Springfield!](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=babylon-5&episode=s04e02) and made more readable by me as I rewatched the relevant part of the episode.)

To be completely nit-picky, there is not 100% confirmation that Kosh knew, but I doubt Kosh would tell Sheridan to jump down into the deep pit with Lorien in it without good reason. And Lorien certainly seems to think that Kosh knew.

Since the Shadows knew that Lorien was there, since the Vorlons share information with each other, since the Vorlons and the Shadows both know things about each other that they're not interested in telling the younger races, and since the First Ones all seem to respect Lorien, it seems plausible that the Vorlons in general know that Lorien is there.

Additionally, JMS has a couple of things to say (quotes taken from the JMS Speaks section of the [Lurker's Guide page for Z'ha'dum](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/countries/us/guide/066.html)).

> [Question:] Did either side foresee Sheridan's leap?
>
> [JMS:] I think the two sides have been too caught up in their own agendas to realize what was happening right under their noses until it was too late... except for Kosh, whose last traces did what they did...for a number of reasons.

This strongly implies that Kosh knew.

> [Question:] 1) Why has Z'ha'dum not been destroyed by the Vorlons et al in one of the previous wars to prevent the Shadows return?
>
> [JMS:] Funny, that...you'd think maybe there was something of interest there.

This strongly implies that the Vorlons knew.

Comment: According to your quote, the Shadows have been driven off Za'ha'dum many times. We know for a fact about once, the last Shadow war, in which the Mimbary already did participate. That's how the Mimbary knew about the Shadows and that planet. Before using "the device", Delenn had Lenir ask Kosh "Have the Shadows returned to Za'ha'dum?" and the answer was "yes". So there is definitely knowledge that the Shadows keep returning to Za'ha'dum. It is highly unlikely that nobody ever investigated why they keep doing that. The Vorlons even know the First One so it's not that hard for them to figure.

Comment: @user1129682 *Minbari

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru is that my only typo? must be a good day then! can't edit the old comment though :-( I'm fairly surprised that Za'ha'dum is actually spelled this way :D

Comment: @user1129682 It isn't, it's Z'ha'dum. (The Minbari one just stood out a lot more and was annoying during the reading - at least to me.)

Comment: @user1129682 Another possible reading of that line is that they're driven off from the galaxy at large in each war and not Z'ha'dum in particular, but that they eventually all regroup on Z'ha'dum. Especially since the Vorlons and Shadows go out of their way to leave each other mostly alone in the wars before the one shown in B5. I'm not really wedded to either interpretation, though.

Comment: @Dranon: 1/2 That doesn't make too much sense, because if "here" just means this galaxy, the position of Lorien becomes too big. An important part of the story about the Shadows and the Vorlons is, that they (both!) are in this galaxy to help the younger races along. The Shadows are clearly evil from our point of view, but the first ones perceive reality/us in a way where the Shadows' way is just one of many equally viable and sensible approaches. The last Shadow war has the primary purpose of establishing that we do not need any further help. Getting rid of some evil is just coincidental.

Comment: @Dranon: 2/2 With the other interpretation it would be established that Lorien is the reason that the Shadows, and quite possibly the Vorlons as well, are in this galaxy, not so much their intention to help. This does not align so nicely with them interfering with the development of the younger races and puts a lot of guilt on Lorien. Also, leaving this galaxy and "us" for good doesn't make as much sense when you believe/live worshipping older races is the way to be.